# IBATIS 2.0 dynamically set table name

Tags: java, sql, spring, ibatis

I want to dynamically set table name in Ibatis select tag.

```
<select id="queryGetTopSongCount" parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT
    count(0)
    FROM 
    #toptable#
</select>
```

Query GetTopSongCount is called as below

```
Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameterMap.put("toptable", "top_of_week_tab_6_2014");

int totalPagination=(Integer)getMainSqlMapClient().queryForObject(queryGetTopSongCount, toptable);
```

I am getting following error

```
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in resources/ibatis/song-sqlMap.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the song.queryGetTopSongCount-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (query failed).  
--- Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''top_of_week_tab_6_2014'' at line 1
```

The issue seems to be with the double quotes. How we can set string parameter without double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of enclosing parameter with hash #toptable#, we need to enclose it with dollar sign $toptable$

```
<select id="queryGetTopSongCount" parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT
    count(0)
    FROM 
    $toptable$
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please explain where did you get this? Because reading the (old) documentation can not give me the answer: there is simply no clear/explicit explanation at all about this difference between # and $

https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

@Hasan Jamshaid has already showed the solution

And the following one also is ok

```
<select id="queryGetTopSongCount" parameterClass="java.lang.String" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT
    count(0)
    FROM 
    ${toptable}
</select>
```